# System.out.println - Java

Tags: java

In Java, why can't we refer to

```
System.out.println
```

as just

```
out.println
```

...why can't the System call just be implicit since the System library is universal? Perhaps Groovy solved this one.

Comment: typical SO, 5 answers to a legit question, 5 downvotes

Comment: It looks more like a complaint than a "legit question" to me.

Comment: there's a question in there

Comment: The question seems to be, "why didn't the language designer make the same design choice I would have made?"  That's not what I'd call a "legit" question.  Probably not an answerable one, either, unless James Gosling happens to be reading this and feels like answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can if you [import `static`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html) like

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

then you can do

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    out.println("Hello, World");
}
```

Comment: IMHO this should be the default somehow, and it should be stdout not just out.

Comment: @AlexMills stdout isn't accurate, since `System.out` can be replaced, and there are disadvantages to making this a default.

Answer (score 3):

"Universal", as you're using it, means that you don't need to import `System`. You still need to qualify references to a field in a different class. What if you (as often happens) want a local field named `out`?

(And Groovy lets you simply use `println`.)

Comment: out should be called stdout and I have never ever seen out as a useful variable name otherwise

Comment: @AlexMills Perhaps if you continue to work with Java you'll run into those scenarios, as I have.

Comment: it wouldn't happen, since System.out is static variable bro, you'd have to have out in your code refer to another class (eg, Chrys.out) or have another static import, or assign a variable to the aforementioned. out is no more a namespace problem than System.

Answer (score 2):

`out.println()` would then eliminate `out` as a valid instance name. By referencing `System` we know that `out` is not, for example, `File out`.